# Limited shopping time

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shopping-cart

How we can set a `timer for shopping`, let say user need to shop with in `10min` other wise his cart will be `expire`, with in that 10 min the product stock will be `reserved` for that `specific user`.

Answer (score 1):

Never used it but I have looked at [cart reservation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cart-reservation-by-plumrocket-inc.html) before

Comment: Yes but is their any free solution :)

Comment: Ah well you didn't say you wanted a free solution. Take a look at https://github.com/GetCommerce/Magento-Reserve-Product but once again I have never used it

Comment: its the right extension but somehow its not working on magento1.9, I'll check this on fresh installation, maybe there its work. Thanks anyway